When two instance of a WPF app using Cefsharp are running, the second one can't initialyse Cef
I have a WPF application using CefSharp to have a web browser integrated in the app.
I noticed that when I start a second instance of my application, the CefSharp initialisation fail. Cef.Initialize(..) return false and in the cef log files I have the following lines :
[25232:20208:1029/140148.801:WARNING:chrome_browser_delegate.cc(693)] Creating a chrome browser without a client
[25232:20208:1029/140148.892:WARNING:chrome_browser_delegate.cc(693)] Creating a chrome browser without a client
[25232:20208:1029/140222.235:WARNING:browser_command_controller.cc(416)] Invalid/disabled command 61458

This failure also open a chromium browser on the desktop. The browser has two tab where the urls are the command lines argument that are passed to my application. So it seem that for some reason when falling the initialisation pass the application argument to the cef executable.
Is there a way to fix the initialisation problem in case of several instance running?
If not, is there at least a way to prevent the unwanted opening of the chromium windows.
I am using CefSharp 129.0.110 with a .NET 4.7.2 application on Windows 10.
Here the code I use to init Cef.
var settings = new CefSettings();
            //enable WebRTC
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ignore-certificate-errors");
            CefSharpSettings.FocusedNodeChangedEnabled = true;
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-gpu", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-webgl", "1");
            settings.LogFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"browser.log");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-logging", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("v", "1");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("touch-events", "1");
            settings.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
            settings.UserAgent = ChromiumHelper.DesktopAgent;

Cef.Initialize(settings,performDependencyCheck: true)


You need a unique CachePath per process instance. See https://github.com/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3615 for background. You can implement https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cd0d144c5064e1c802dec861f5c715f416d92763/CefSharp/Handler/IBrowserProcessHandler.cs#L65 to detect multiple relaunches if you wish to use the same behavior as Chromium (which is to create multiple windows in the same process)

@amaitland Thank for your anwser. I solved the problem of poping browser windows by implementing IBrowserProcessHandler.
