CefSharp multi instance/run webbrowser?
when using cefsharp in netforms/wpf and i try to start the app for a second time it opens correctly but in taskmanager the apps are in different main processes.
image
i have tried allot of different mhs/fns like using Mutex (server+pipeline) and a few other things that did not really work.
im trying to use easytabs with cefsharp. but its just not working for multi instance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79137457/when-two-instance-of-a-wpf-app-using-cefsharp-are-running-the-second-one-cant#comment139566170_79137457
